# How to make database transactions in scheduled tasks in Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, transactions, scheduled-tasks

Can anyone give me an example of how to call DB transactions in scheduled tasks by using Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, please? Thank you very much.

I used Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE to create a scheduled task through `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`, and used `@Autowired` to get an instance of `JpaRepository`.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void importDataFromDat() {
    List records = datUploadRecordRepository.findAllByImportTime();

    for (DatUploadRecord record : records) {

        record.setImportTime(new Date());
        datUploadRecordRepository.save(record);
  //    datUploadRecordRepository.updateImportTime(new Date(), record.getId());
    }
}
```

1. It can return results of select SQL, but it cannot save entities to the DB.
2. If I create my own update method in my own JpaRepository rather than calling the save() method, it will cause the bug below:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing
>   an update/delete query; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:55)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.updateImportTime(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] at
>   com.crane.schedules.ImportToDBFromDAT.importDataFromDat(ImportToDBFromDAT.java:65)
>   ~[classes/:na] at
>   com.crane.schedules.ImportToDBFromDAT$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$847b3ccb.invoke()
>   ~[classes/:na] at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   com.crane.schedules.ImportToDBFromDAT$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$971e70c9.importDataFromDat()
>   ~[classes/:na] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60] at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_60] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_60] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_60] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_60] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_60] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_60] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing
>   an update/delete query at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:242)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE] ... 31 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: I'd say the update method on your repository need to be Transactional. Not the Scheduled task.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I made the update method be Transactional, but the result is the same as above.

Comment: Has your Spring boot properly activated the transactional management ?
(I.e. do you added the annotations `@EnableAutoConfiguration`  
`@EnableJpaRepositories`
`@EnableTransactionManagement` in you configuration class ?)

Comment: Yes, I did add these annotations in my DB configuration class and my application class.

Comment: I am struggling with similar issue....need to update the db from scheduled task....and the scheduled task method is in service class.......see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792216/spring-boot-task-to-update-foreign-key-in-db?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but could you not create an independant transactional `Component` that manage the operation and then call it from the task?

In our application, we used a scheduled task to purge document. It call document service to get all the docs (transactional operation) and then purge each doc (purge method from document service is transactional too)

Answer (score 0):

I got such issue solved with wrapping the body of `importDataFromDat()` to a separate method annotated with `@Transactional` of another class and creating a method annotated with `@Async` that is called from `importDataFromDat()`

P.S. don't forget to add `@EnableAsync` to the configuration