# Spring boot task to update foreign key in DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on  REST API using Spring boot which is going to manage the auction of items.

Users participating in auction will be in a separate **Users table**

Items to be Auctioned will be in **Auction_items table**, along with auction start and end time, winner null if auction is still in progress.

All the bids done by users for respective items are there in **Bids table**

I have already tried different ways(cron, fixedRate, fixedDelay) for scheduling the task, got a similar error for all of them, **I am suspecting there might be a DB issue due to which it is happening.**

Below are the tables and corresponding model class along  with service and repository interface.

**USERS TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
USER_ID SERIAL,
NAME VARCHAR(200),
EMAIL VARCHAR(200),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(200),
PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID)
);
```

**AUCTION_ITEMS TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE AUCTION_ITEMS
(
ITEM_ID SERIAL,
ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(200),
ITEM_DESCRIPTION TEXT,
START_TIME TIMESTAMP,
END_TIME TIMESTAMP,
STARTING_AMOUNT INT,
WINNER INT,
PRIMARY KEY(ITEM_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(WINNER) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**BIDS TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE BIDS
(
BID_ID SERIAL,
ITEM_ID INT,
USER_ID INT,
AMOUNT INT,
PRIMARY KEY(BID_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(ITEM_ID) REFERENCES AUCTION_ITEMS(ITEM_ID) ON DELETE 
CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Below are the model classes for above tables:

**User.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {

@Id
private Integer user_id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;

//getter setter methods
}
```

**Item.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AUCTION_ITEMS")
public class Item {

@Id
private Integer item_id;
private String item_name;
private String item_description;
private Timestamp start_time;
private Timestamp end_time;
private int starting_amount;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="winner")
private User user;

//getter setter methods
}
```

**Bid.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BIDS")
public class Bid {

@Id
private Integer bid_id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="item_id")
private Item item;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;
private int amount;
//getter setter nethods
}
```

Below is the service class, where I am defining the **scheduledTask() method** to run and calculate the winner of Item auctioned once the end time of auction item is passed:

**ItemService.java:**

```
@Service
public class ItemService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public List<Item> getAllItems(){
        return (List<Item>) itemRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Object getItem(Integer id) {
        Item i = itemRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        if(i.getUser()!=null) {
            return i.getUser();
        }
        else {
            //will be returning highest bid amount for that particular item
            return itemRepository.getMaxBid(id);
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="20 36 17 * * ?")
    public void scheduledTask() {
        List<Item> listOfItems = (List<Item>)itemRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("going to update DB");
        for(Item i : listOfItems) {
            Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(time.equals(i.getEnd_time()) || time.after(i.getEnd_time())) {
                if(i.getUser() == null) {
                    Integer item_id = i.getItem_id();
                    Integer winner_id = itemRepository.findWinner(item_id);
                    User u= userRepository.findById(winner_id).orElse(null);

                    i.setUser(u);
                    System.out.println("updated");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**ItemRepository.java:**

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item,Integer>{

@Query(value="select max(b.amount) from bids as b where b.item_id=?1", 
nativeQuery=true )
public Integer getMaxBid(Integer item_id);

@Query(value="select b.user_id from bids as b where b.item_id=?1 AND 
b.amount = (select max(amount) from bids);", nativeQuery=true)
public Integer findWinner(Integer id);
```

Below is the error which I get once, the time comes to update the data in table:

> 2019-04-22 12:55:30.123  INFO 9100 --- [   scheduling-1] >o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using >ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   going to update DB
>   2019-04-22 12:55:30.464 ERROR 9100 --- [   scheduling-1] ?>o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in >scheduled task.
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: >org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral >ordinal; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: >org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral >ordinal
>     at >org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExcepti>onIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:373) ~[spring-orm->5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPo>ssible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm->]>5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExcepti>onIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm->5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.transla>teExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~
>   [spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAcce>ssUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.in>voke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx->5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Reflecti>veMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcess>or$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPos>tProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Reflecti>veMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(Expose>InvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Reflecti>veMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetect>orMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.ja>va:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Reflecti>veMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProx>y.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.findUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>     at auction.demo.service.ItemService.scheduledTask(ItemService.java:55) >~[classes/:na]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~
>   [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) >~[na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.>java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledM>ethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(De>legatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context->5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(Rescheduli>ngRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
>   [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
>   [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$2>01(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Sche>duledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:114>2) [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:61>7) [na:1.8.0_121]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

**Question:** Create a scheduled task which runs when at the auction end time of an item and decides the winner of that item from Bids table and stores the Id of that user in Winner column of Auction_items table.

I think the reason behind above Error is, I have **created a User member variable in model class, but in table side, it is expecting only the id of User not the complete User instance**.

Even if this is the reason, I am not sure how to solve it, also **if this is not the reason, will the application automatically store the proper user_id in winner column, if proper user instance is set using setUser().**

Note that I have used @EnabledScheduling in the class, with main() method.

**UPDATE:** Pasted new ItemService.java, Item.java
In Item.java I have used datatype User for the member variable since making it as Integer was not working

Comment: Have you tried to remove the semicolon at end of query?

Comment: Yup, it didn't work, it threw another exception:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: I think return type is invalid so change that to List<User> instead of user.

Comment: return type of which method, findUser returns only one user instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so in the scheduledTask() method of ItemService.java, control was reaching every part and item instance 'i' was also getting updated, I guess I just needed to save that to DB using itemRepository.save(i)
Below is the complete implementation of scheduledTask() method

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 17 11 * * ?")
    public void scheduledTask() {
        List<Item> listOfItems = (List<Item>)itemRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("going to update DB");
        for(Item i : listOfItems) {
            Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(time.equals(i.getEnd_time()) || time.after(i.getEnd_time())) {
                if(i.getUser() == null) {
                    Integer item_id = i.getItem_id();
                    Integer winner_id = itemRepository.findWinner(item_id);
                    User u= userRepository.findById(winner_id).orElse(null);

                    i.setUser(u);
                    itemRepository.save(i);//change in code, which seems to work now
                    System.out.println("printing item:");
                    System.out.println(i.getItem_description()+", "+i.getItem_name()+", "+i.getStarting_amount()+", "+i.getItem_id()+", "+i.getEnd_time()+", "+i.getStart_time()+", "+i.getUser().getUser_id());
                    System.out.println("updated");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. a repository is supposed to manage one domain type (entity), in your case you are using `ItemRepository` to fetch User entities which is incorrect usage.
2. you don't need to implement `findUser` method since repositories already have implementation for `findById`.
3. I would recommend that you try to use JPA Query Methods for such simple queries instead of resorting to native SQL queries.

So short answer, create a separate `UserRepository`, move `findWinner` method there, and use the existing`findById` of the `UserRepository` instead of `findUser` of `ItemRepository`

Comment: Yup there is a separate USerRepository and I was using findById method only, I just included everything here since both return the same thing, thought to shorten it a bit

Comment: Well as you can see that CrudRepository takes two type parameters, the ID type for the entity and entity itself, this makes a repository very specific to one entity and thus should not be used to work with other domain types.

Comment: okay even if we have a custom query?
But coming to present question, I used userRepository.findById(winner_id) method, now I am getting this exception, I think we are narrowing down to main problem:

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: auction.demo.models.User, at table: auction_items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(winner)]

Comment: I believe this is because the foreign key for user in the auction table is of type `INT` however the primary key in the Users table is `Serial`

Comment: Yup I also suspect that, but I am not sure how to remove this.

Comment: you just need to alter the column type in AUCTION_ITEMS, either run the SQL directly on your database or better yet add as a migration script if you're using some migration tool such as flyway or liquibase

Comment: but since I am using the winner column as foreign key, it is having the user_id which will reference the users table, not sure what should I update Column type to....?

Comment: The foreign key column will have a copy of the primary key value, so consequently the foreign key column type must match the type of the primary key it references.

Comment: You suggesting to change serial of user_id to Integer in Users table ?

Comment: As a work around I changed the data type of member variable user in model class Item to Integer and in Service method, just doing, i.setWinner(winner_id); in the end.

Doing this removes the error, execution comes to this point and all, but it is still not updated on DB

Comment: no I am suggesting you update the foreign key column (winner_id) type to match the primary key type of the users table

Comment: actually it seems that int should be accepted also because serial is a type of integer :|

Comment: Yep it should be accepted although I explicitly changed the type to integer, but got the same exception.

Comment: can you update your code samples above since now we're trying to fix a new issue other than the original (which we fixed already)

Comment: I have pasted the updated ItemService.java, Item.java 
As you can see, I have added 2 sysouts in scheduledTask method, one saying "going to update db" and other says "updated", this time no error is thrown, both sysouts printed, but db updation not done yet.

Comment: yes because you need to call `itemRepository.save(i)` after `i.setUser(u)` in order to persist the changes you made to the entity

Comment: Yea, it's solved now, I was very near to solution, but moving round and round :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192270/discussion-between-akki-and-ahmed-abdelhady).